# Read data to table view from firebase in real time

Tags: swift, database, xcode, firebase

Hello I am writing and retrieving data from firebase, after writing some data I need to close the app and reopen to see the data that added.

```
private let ref = Database.database().reference().child("categories")
   viewDidLoad(){
self.ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for user_child in (snapshot.children) {
                
                let user_snap = user_child as! DataSnapshot
                let dict = user_snap.value as! [String: Any]
                
                self.categoryId.append(user_snap.key)
                
            }
        })
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: updated my post :) @Mat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you successfully present the data in your app, but you want your data in real time, so that your data view (tableview or whatever) is updated every time there’s a change in the database.

`viewDidLoad` is called only when the viewController is created, that’s why your new data is not fetched until you restart the app.

You could keep the `observeSingleEvent` but make the call in `viewWillAppear` or some other function, instead of `viewDidLoad`.

However, a better way is to use `observe` instead of `observeSingleEvent`. This call can be made from `viewDidLoad`; your data will update in real time.

**Update**

You can just switch to observe instead of observeSingleEvent.

```
self.ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    // Handle your data
})
```

Please refer to the docs for more context (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)

**Update 2**

This is how you avoid duplicates in your data array:

```
self.ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

    // Create an array to deal with the updated data
    let updatedCategoryIds = [String]()
    
    for user_child in (snapshot.children) {
            
        let user_snap = user_child as! DataSnapshot
        let dict = user_snap.value as! [String: Any]
        updatedCategoryIds.append(user_snap.key)
            
    }

    self.categoryIds = updatedCategoryIds

    // Now that self.categoryIds holds real time data without duplicates you can present the data 
})
```

Comment: Hey thanks for helping me! Can you show me how the code needs to look with observe instead of observeSingleEvent? 
Thank you !

Comment: Congrats! It’s showing the data in real time, buttt this is doubling the data now

Comment: @adirbuilder hold on and I’ll update my answer

Comment: Ok @adirbuilder, check it out

Answer (score -1):

This is the function that fetches data if you have pushed new data to your dataBase

```
extension YourViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    
    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        
        //Fetch Your Data

    }
    
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for trying solving my issue! what i have to put into this func?

Comment: you have to put the process of fetching your data. It will re load data from your dataBase every time you upload something new.

Comment: Can you please send me example of this fetching ?

Comment: @AisultanAskarov you should try and help the OP use what they already have. In this case the OP was close to the solution with the code that they used